# Angular 4 - @ViewChild component is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have a toast notification component called `ToastComponent` which I want to call from any other component. I implemented it like this:

`ToastComponent`:

```
export class ToastComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  showToast() {
    // some code
  }
}
```

`app.component.html`:

```
<llqa-main-container>
  <llqa-header></llqa-header>
  <div class="content-container">
    <main class="content-area">
      <llqa-toast></llqa-toast> <!-- ToastComponent which I want to call -->
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
  </div>
</llqa-main-container>
```

`UserManagementComponent` which is inside the `<router-outlet>`:

```
export class UserManagementComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(ToastComponent) toast: ToastComponent;

  constructor() {}

  someSaveMethod() {
    this.toast.showToast() // throws error below
  }
}
```

On calling the `someSaveMethod()` method, I'll get the error that `toast` is undefined.

If I take `<llqa-toast></llqa-toast>`out of the `app.component.html` and put it on top of the `user-management.component.html`, it works fine, but then I have to put it in every component. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Where is `someSaveMethod` being called? Try to check with `console.log()` statements whether the constructor of `ToastComponent` is called before your call to `someSaveMethod`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since in your case, the `ToastComponent` is used in the grand parent (`AppComponent`), that's why you are getting this error. One way to avoid this error is to use `Subject` defined in some shared service. I am using that approach in my project to show toast notifications. Here is how you can do it:

---

Keep your `<llqa-toast></llqa-toast>` in `app.component.html`.

Define a service to basically emit an event and subscribe to that event in your `ToastComponent`. For example,

> UtilityService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UtilityService {

    public OnShowToast = new Subject<boolean>();

    public showToast(): void {
        this.OnShowToast.next(true);
    }
}
```

You need to inject this service in your `AppModule` providers. Now `subscribe` to the `OnShowToast` event in your `ToastComponent`.

> ToastComponent:

```
import { UtilityService } from './path/to/the/utility.service';
export class ToastComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private readonly utilityService: UtilityService) { }

  ngOnInit() { 
     this.utilityService.OnShowToast.subscribe(value =>
        {
            this.showToast();
        });
  }

  private showToast() {
    // some code
  }
}
```

Now, you can call the `showToast()` method of the `UtilityService` from any component you want. For example,

> UserManagementComponent

```
export class UserManagementComponent implements OnInit {

  // You dont need this now
  // @ViewChild(ToastComponent) toast: ToastComponent;

  constructor(private readonly utilityService: UtilityService) {}

  someSaveMethod() {
    this.utilityService.showToast();
  }
}
```

Comment: `EventEmitter` is not supposed to be used in services. An `Observable` or `Subject` does the same. `EventEmitter` is supposed to be used **only** for `@Output()`s.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Didn't know that, since it was also working without any issues in my service. Thanks. Updating my code here as well to use `Subject` instead.

Comment: Currently it's working because `EventEmitter` just extends `Subject` (AFAIR), but the Angular team can change this without prior notice to a custom implementation that still works for `@Output()` but might break other uses, because `@Output()` is the only thing `EventEmitter` is supposed to be used for.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the detailed info, +1