# Angular 4 Events with EventEmitter

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I made a service named UserEvents

```
@Injectable()
export class UserEvents {

public evAuthenticated: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

public AuthUserEvent(email: string) {
this.evAuthenticated.next(email);
  }
}
```

I included this service with the providers in AppModule

I have a service name AuthService that include the UserEvents and emits:

```
this.userEvents.evAuthenticated.emit(email);
```

And another service that suscribe

```
constructor(private userEvents: UserEvents){
this.userEvents.evAuthenticated.subscribe((data: string) => this.SetUser(data));
}

private SetUser(email: string) {
   this.logger.info('Event triggered with ' + email);
}
```

But the suscription is never triggered.  At list, SetUser is never called.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Dont use event emitter in your services: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter. Use a shared service instead: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: Use a Subject instead of EventEmitter

Comment: EventEmitter inherits from Subject: `export declare class EventEmitter<T> extends Subject<T> {`

Answer (score 4):

From my knowledge of Angular 2(+), EventEmitters are to be used as **Component Outputs**, i.e.:

```ts
 @Output() myStringOutput = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

If you need a triggerable event in your services, it is recommended to use RxJS Subjects, like so:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  private _onMyEvent = new Subject<string>();
  public get onMyEvent(): Observable { return this._onMyEvent.asObservable(); }

  public trigger(value: string) {
    this._onMyEvent.next(value);
  }
}
```

And elsewhere in your code, you can do something like this:

```ts
this.myService.onMyEvent.subscribe((value: string) => console.log('Triggered!', value));
this.myService.trigger('Hello World')
```

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/CEgfs5tajRmElZfVS0Oy).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Subject` instead:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserEvents {

    public evAuthenticated = new Subject<string>();

    public AuthUserEvent(email: string) {
        this.evAuthenticated.next(email);
    }
}
```

Keep your subscription code as it is.

Check comment from **Günter Zöchbauer** on my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45710245/1791913

> EventEmitter is not supposed to be used in services. An Observable or
>   Subject does the same. EventEmitter is supposed to be used only for
>   @Output()s. EventEmitter just extends Subject (AFAIR), but the Angular
>   team can change this without prior notice to a custom implementation
>   that still works for @Output() but might break other uses, because
>   @Output() is the only thing EventEmitter is supposed to be used for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, but both are not required in Angular 4.
I found the problem: the service that suscribe is not instanciated automatically.
I added the service in the constructor of app.component and everything began to work.